Should I not save both access and refresh tokens to cookies?
I am implementing authorization token logic in my web app server using react and nestjs.
I understand storing token in cookie is the safest among client side storage.(ex localStorage). so I am storing refresh token in cookie.
but when it comes to access token. is it better to avoid cookie?
I heard storing both token(access refresh) in cookie is risky to CSRF attack.
and there might be some devices that don't support cookie.
another thing is that I need to share tokens between sub domains (I know this is possible using cookie). if I want this, can I share only refresh token?
to sum up
1.storing both access refresh to cookie
2.storing refresh in cookie and access in somewhare else maybe localstorage.
which is better?
and is the 2th method also appropriate for sub domain environment?
Thanks!

Option 1- (Storing both in cookies) can work if you use strong CSRF protection mechanisms (e.g., CSRF tokens or SameSite cookie attributes). If you do, this can simplify token sharing across subdomains, but remember to keep the access token short-lived.
This method simplifies token sharing across subdomains because cookies handle this automatically, but you need to ensure the access token's lifespan is short to limit exposure if compromised.
Option 2- (Refresh token in cookie, access token in localStorage) provides better CSRF protection but introduces some risks with XSS. It can work in a subdomain environment, but the access token won’t be shared automatically across subdomains. You’ll have to rely on refresh tokens to request new access tokens as needed on each subdomain.
Sharing tokens across subdomains requires additional logic to refresh access tokens as needed on each domain, adding complexity.
Given your requirement for sharing between subdomains, Option 1 with CSRF protection might be simpler for your use case.

thanks for good answer and the explanation is excellent!!

@Shawn No. Dont save access token in localStorage. Instead, save it in memory by creating a variable, making it function as a session token (but not session token). This way, on every refresh or a new tab, it generates a new access token and you can pass it through sockets. This is more secure and practical approach.
